# Rest Api for odoo

Tags: rest, odoo, rpc, xml-rpc

To use odoo On an application ios, i use protocol rpc, i receive xml and i parse it, it's the first time i use it, the client told me that  we can use Rest Api for odoo with this :

https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/12.0/muk_rest/

The question if i use this module so i will switch to protocol Rest Api, this gonna help me to gain time on my developement ?  and it's have better security ? because i can see that it's use a token for OAuth

Thank's you for your responses

Comment: So this question is about XML-RPC vs. REST in context of faster development?

Comment: yes  and context security 
but i dont know if this module offer all rest fonctionnality https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/12.0/muk_rest/

Answer (score 0):

I'm from MuK IT. To reply to Tamtoum1987 comment. Our REST API can handle both OAuth1 and all 4 variants of OAuth2. If you have the choice, OAuth2 is the modern option. I think the best choice to test if the API meets your requirements is to just try it out.

Swagger: https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis-docs/keshrath/muk_rest/3.0.0/

Examples: https://github.com/muk-it/muk_docs/blob/12.0/muk_rest/examples/examples.md